# Using HTML input as function parameter causing infinite loop

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I've made a prime factor calculator in JavaScript and am trying to display it on my website. I want to be able to let the user choose the input, however whenever I submit the input it causes an infinite loop. I have narrowed down the cause to the code I'm using as the parameter for the function.

Here is the HTML:

```
      <div class="pf-calculator-instructions-wrapper"><p class="pf-calculator-instructions">
        <em>Input a number to the field below. Output will appear above. Maximum 15 digits.</em></p>
      </div>
      <input id="pf-input" type="number" maxlength="15" class="pf-calculator-input"/>
      <button class="submit-button" onclick="findPrimeFactors(document.getElementById('pf-input').value)">Submit</button>
```

I've tried it so the function with just a number (10) as the parameter and it worked fine, but when changing it to take the input value instead (still 10) the page just freezes like I'm causing an infinite loop. Am I missing something here?

Thanks!

Comment: 1) Without your js of findPrimeFactors there is no way we can debug this. 2) Are you converting the input string value to a number?

Comment: Thank you very much! I assumed that it would already be a number rather than a string due to the input type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, I hadn't converted my input from a string to an integer. I wrongly assumed that it would already be in this format due to the input type being number.